# Unix terminal: Open the current folder, how?

Tags: ubuntu, mac, terminal

I know open the current folder in terminal (Mac OSX) typing:

```
open .
```

But in Linux, how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your file manager, but generally, you can do something like this:

`$FILEMANAGER .`

If yours is Nautilus, then:

`nautilus .`

Yours could be anything from Nautilus to `mc`. I suggest you find out the name of it to do this.

Comment: Yeah that works! Thanks. I'm using Ubuntu 11.04